# Code with syntax highlighting in a word processor

Tags: syntax-highlighting, word-processor

How can I get code with syntax highlighting into a word processor?

It's for a manual that will have code examples which should be able to go from page to page so putting images is not an option.

I'd rather do it with OpenOffice but I could also use iWorks or Office. The code is Ruby, Java, Python and maybe others. I could use TextMate to export it if necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XCode does that already, I think.  If you copy out of its window and paste into another app that accepts rich text, the formatting comes along with it.  I just made a screenshot:

[screenshot http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/8756/xcodetextedit.png](http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/8756/xcodetextedit.png)

Comment: Visual Studio too, that I know. But sadly not a viable option for the choice of languages.

Comment: XCode highlights python and java for sure.  I don't have a ruby file to try.  I pasted into TextEdit, MS Word, and some others.

Comment: I just made a test ruby file, and that worked too.  Looks like this should cover the OP's question?

Answer (score 6):

VIM has a syntax hilighing for almost every programming language, and has option to export hilighted source as HTML file that should be easily imported by word processor. Use

```
:TOhtml
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to copy/paste correctly highlighted Java code from Eclipse into Word 2007 and Word 2010 by selecting not the regular Paste, but Paste Special->Rich Text Format.

"Paste Special" is found by clicking the little down arrow under the Paste icon on the Word Ribbon Bar.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.fauskes.net/nb/syntaxms/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html